# Url doesn't match url-pattern in web.xml

Tags: java, servlets

In the web.xml file I have this url pattern:

```
<url-pattern>/servletPrueba/*</url-pattern>
```

and in the jsp file I have this link:

```
<a href="servletPrueba/a">Enlace servlet</a>
```

But I get a 404 error, I think the url matches the url pattern, doesn't it?

here is the servlet,it's onle a test purposes servlet,only for practice

```
package pruebas;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class servletPrueba
 */
//@WebServlet("/servletPrueba")
public class servletPrueba extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public servletPrueba() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        RequestDispatcher despachador = null;
        String ruta = request.getPathInfo();    
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(request.getPathInfo());
        out.println(request.getServletPath());


    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //doGet(request, response);
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("POST");
    }

}
```

webb.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>pruebas</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>servletPrueba</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pruebas.servletPrueba</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servletPrueba</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servletPrueba/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Where is the JSP located? This link can only work if the JSP is located in the webapp root.

Comment: The jsp it's in the webapp folder

Comment: Can you post your servlet?

Comment: of couse,the servlet is posted

Comment: You can check the URL generated by <a> and copy past it in browser and check. And try to call servlet by browser and check, it may help you in debug the problem.
URL for servlet: <hostid>:<port>/<projectname>/servletPrueba/<any string>.
And check where your servlet doget method call or not, you may get some idea.

Comment: the generated url is the expected `http://localhost:8080/pruebas/servletPrueba/a` but with the `<url-pattern>/servletPrueba/*</url-pattern>` the only thing I get is a 404 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete example (I did not use Maven, however I could) :
[image: Eclipse Screen]

[image: How it looks in browser]

Comment: This way is taking the literal value ,the url is pageContext.request.contextPath}/servletPrueba/a

Comment: Interesting, could you please post complete web.xml? Or complete servlet-mapping for this entry.

Comment: the xml is now posted on the original post